# Firebase admin sdk unauthenticated query to secondary firestore DB

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

**Scenario:** I have a firestore document(**document 1**) in Database(**DATABASE 1)** that is publicly readable i.e I can make a REST GET call unauthenticated and get the data.

I have another firestore Database(**DATABASE 2**), in which i want to clone
data of **document 1** and save it to **DATABASE 2** document.

**Question**: How can i retrieve the **DATABASE 1** **document 1** data from **DATABASE 2** Admin SDK ?

**Motivation:** REST response requires parsing, i am hoping to make Firebase lib SDK call that doesnt requires any parsing.

**FEW NOTES:**

- I don't want to expose DATABASE 2 Service Account Creds to DATABASE 1 Admin.

Wondering if its possible to create secondary instance of firebase Admin using **DATABASE 1** `project-id` and/or `url` without exposing and creds.

Comment: Accessing the database using the Admin SDK requires that you specify administrative credentials. But you might want to have a look at the regular (non-administrative) Node.js SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible, **but you are going to need to expose credentials for a service account in the second project in order to use the admin sdk for that**. If this is possible in your case, all you have to do is instantiate the project with a `firebaseOptions` referencing to a different project, as you can see in [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#node.js):

```
const secondaryServiceAccount = require('./path/to/serviceAccountKey.json');

const secondaryAppConfig = {
    credential: admin.credential.cert(secondaryServiceAccount),
    projectId: "YOUR_SECOND_PROJECT_ID"
};

const secondary = admin.initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig, 'secondary');
```

and access whatever services you need by using the `secondary` variable, eg. to access the second Firestore project use `secondary.firestore()`.

As mentioned by Frank in the comments an alternative to this is to use the regular Firestore SDK, you can find more information in [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#multiple-projects), the process is quite similar.